# Pass value into @include by default

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

### Long story short

How can I define a default value for a record in `@include`? Here is my code:

```
// view - questions.create
@include('questions.__answer', ['number' => 0]) // <-- 'answer' => null by DEFAULT

// view - questions.edit
@include('questions.__answer', ['number' => $index, 'answer' => $answer])
```

### Additional details

As you see, I have create / edit views for a `Question` model, which contains multiple possible answers. The html code for a single answer is located in a separate partial view to eliminate code duplication. I need to reuse this view both for answer creation, where new record should be created **from scratch**, and editing of an existing answer, whose fields should be populated with **existing data**.

I certainly could pass `'answer' => null` **explicitly**, but I prefer it to be passed **implicitly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never found a great way to do this either, so I had to make a little hack.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1844

There are a lot of ways of setting variables, but pick your favorite. Mine was using a `@set`.

Then, at the top of the include, do this.

```
@set('number', isset($number) ? $number : null);
```

Yeah, I know, it's gross. I never played around with View Composers, though, and you may be able to make use of this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers

Theoretically, you could use `view()` and a ViewComposer to render a partial template inline with Blade and tuck away all that nasty logic into OOP where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I settled for just checking if a value is set in the included view.